# Go with GWT + AppEngine or LAMP? Existing Java Developer

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, lamp

I'm a Java developer, and am building out my first SaaS web application. I am very new to Web programming

Tried out Ruby On Rails first, but decided not to pursue that.

I'm planning a new web app and one of my considerations is that I want it to run well on mobile browsers as well as desktop browsers. I also plan to publish a public API for this application, and build native mobile applications

I am quite impressed with GWT + AppEngine, and its ability to hide the complexities of Javascript. Also, its a boon for current Java programmers.

I am also reading up on LAMP, and it seems fairly straightforward as well. The learning curve would be a bit more, but I would get more control on the Database and use SQL as well

The primary question is: GWT + AppEngine or LAMP? Considerations:

- **Learning curve**: GWT seems simpler
- **Hiring programmers**: LAMP seems to have a much wider talent pool than folks familiar with GWT
- Multiple applications using the same **DB**: LAMP seems to win here, maybe AppEngine is good too, but couldn't find much.
- **Widget libraries**: Plain GWT looks a bit boring, seems like there are more options for LAMP

I guess I am a bit confused,, and need to pick a technology to build out the product.

Any tips, suggestions or directions appreciated.

Comment: by GWT you mean Google-App-Engine right? (Hover over the GWT tag)

Comment: Yes, I mix the terminology up sometimes, although it is clear in my mind.

Comment: There are web sites written in both - both will work. I am a GWT developer currently and we use GXT for our front end library as a layer on top of GWT. As far as having control of the backend database, GWT on the server is really a bunch of Servlets and you can use whatever mechanism you want to access backend systems.

Comment: For a simple task, I'm using GAE without GWT, and now I'm switching from plain javascript to jquery for the client code. I guess my election is due to the fact that I don't need a big database, so JDO will do just fine. For large amounts of storage, the lack of support for a relational database my be an issue. Also, remember that GAE does not support many java libraries for the server side of the project (although they seem to be improving on that aspect). Unfortunately, I don't have experience in lamp (thus, this blurb is a comment and not an answer). As @svrist said, try hem first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the GWT only gives you client-side code, so you would need some kind of backend anyway. That means that you get full control over database and sql if you want to.

That said, you could even have frontend code generated with GWT which communicates with **P** HP scripts with **M** ysql DB  on an **A** pache server on **L** inux.

The essens might be: Do more research and atleast code something on either before you take the decision

Comment: Thanks! I think its best to try both out and see what I am comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you aren't really qualified to be taking on this project... therefore, LAMP... you'll find more support and more flexibility to abet your efforts well into the future..

Comment: He starts saying "I am very new to Web programming" (sic). So he has very valid questions. What makes you believe one person you don't even know is qualified or not for a project you don't know anything about?

Answer (score 0):

you could go very far with GAE/J + some JSP.

I recommend Flex for the front end

Comment: Thanks!, I am trying to sway away from Flex to avoid the Adobe Flash installation availability on some tablets.